# SQS queue: The request must contain the parameter MessageBody

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to call the sqs queue from cloudshell with the following command: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-making-api-requests-xml.html#sqs-api-constructing-endpoints)

```
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-6-39-219 ~]$  curl https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/632547665100/myqueue?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=Your%20message%20text
```

And I  get the following response:

```
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-6-39-219 ~]$ <?xml version="1.0"?><ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>MissingParameter</Code><Message>The request must contain the parameter MessageBody.</Message><Detail/></Error><RequestId>a036828f-4b5f-50d0-9ee2-df9e1b702f5f</RequestId></ErrorResponse> curl https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/632547665100/myqueue?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=Your%20message%20tex
```

Comment: I can confirm your findings. Not sure what's happening. As an alternative, you could try a POST request, or use the AWS CLI: `aws sqs send-message --queue-url xxx --message-body xxx`